# Google Maps Move Circle

Tags: android

I'm using google maps api and would like to draw a cricle on my position when im moving. Every thing is ok when i start but when move the circle stays on position.

```
 private void setSearchCircle(LatLng newLatlng) {
    if (googleMap != null) {
        radiusCircle = googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(newLatlng)
                .radius(SEARCH_RADIUS)
                .fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
                .strokeColor(mActivity.getResources().getColor(R.color.detail_grey))
                .strokeWidth(8));
    }
}


  private void moveSearchCircle(LatLng newLatlng) {
    if(radiusCircle != null){
        radiusCircle.setCenter(newLatlng);
    }
}

 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        lastLatitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        lastLongitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(lastLatitude, lastLongitude);
        moveSearchCircle(currentLatLng);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the result of ``location`` in ``onLocationChanged``

Comment: i get cyclic position updates..i'm using this in fragment i should tell

Answer (score -2):

So i found my problem..when i use the location directly like

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
if (mLastLocation != null) {
    LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    moveSearchCircle(currentLatLng);
  } }
```

i works like expected

Comment: this can't be the issue. Maybe you had no issue to begin with?